# Not able to create a new Flutter project through Command Prompt

Tags: flutter

It shows me Multiple output directories specified when I try to create a new Flutter Project using the command `flutter create MyApp`.

Comment: Can you explain more about your issue ?

Comment: Can Someone help me in building a app (actually a social media app). I am following a YouTube video but I am facing many problems. Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing because, you can't use `MyApp` to create a flutter app.

The name should be all lowercase, with underscores to separate words, just_like_this. Use only basic Latin letters and Arabic digits: [a-z0-9_]. Also, make sure the name is a valid Dart identifier—that it doesn’t start with digits and isn’t a reserved word.

for more visit : https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#name

Comment: Thank You! I am a beginner. So it might be a silly question.Sorry for disturbation.And it is also my first Stack Overflow question